# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta eloquent con diferentes filtros?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Estoy creando un filtro de busqueda con diferentes parametros de busquedas, lo hago es buscar todas las practicas registradas y si se ingresa algun parametro para buscar, entonces la consulta se modifica segun las condicones, de la siguiente manera:

filtro:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

consulta desde el controlador:

```
$practices = Practice::whereHas('student', function ($student) use ($search, $run){
                $student->whereHas('person', function ($person) use ($search, $run){
                    $person->select()
                        ->where('full_nombre', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
                        ->orWhere('run', 'LIKE', '%'.$run.'%')
                        ->orderBy('primer_apellido', 'ASC');
                });
            })->where([
                ['service_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$service.'%'],
                ['course_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$course.'%'],
                ['training_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$training.'%'],
                ['stage_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$stage.'%'],
                ['state_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$state.'%'],
                ['institution_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$institucion.'%'],
                ['inicio', '<=', $fecha_inicio.'%'],
            ])
            ->orderBy('state_id', 'ASC')
            ->orderBy('inicio', 'ASC')
            ->paginate();
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, si los campos se encuentran vacios entonces muestra todas las practicas y sino, busca las practicas segun los parametros ingresados, salvo por la "Fecha Termino" que si la agrego a la condición where entonces no me muestra ninguna practica cuando los campos estan vacios y solo las muestra cuando se ingresa una "fecha termino", con la "fecha de inicio" funciona todo bien, pero no entiendo por qué la fecha de termino no

sin "fecha termino":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agregando la condicion al where:

```
$practices = Practice::whereHas('student', function ($student) use ($search, $run){
                $student->whereHas('person', function ($person) use ($search, $run){
                    $person->select()
                        ->where('full_nombre', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
                        ->orWhere('run', 'LIKE', '%'.$run.'%')
                        ->orderBy('primer_apellido', 'ASC');
                });
            })->where([
                ['service_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$service.'%'],
                ['course_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$course.'%'],
                ['training_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$training.'%'],
                ['stage_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$stage.'%'],
                ['state_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$state.'%'],
                ['institution_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$institucion.'%'],
                ['inicio', '>=', $fecha_inicio.'%'],
                ['termino', '<=', $fecha_termino.'%']
            ])
            ->orderBy('state_id', 'ASC')
            ->orderBy('inicio', 'ASC')
            ->paginate();
```

Resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: has probado a usar el whereBeetween()

Comment: hola @HeynerMartinez si lo probé, pero la busqueda no necesariamente debe tener una  fecha de termino, se puede buscar las practicas que empiezan desde '$fecha' o que terminan hasta '$fecha' o ambas juntas

Comment: Para que le concatenas el .'%'?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ era para mantener la logica de la condición LIKE, traté de quitarlo pero me arroja un error que dice "Illegal operator and value combination." en la condicion where 'termino' <= $fecha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buen día,

Cuando crees filtros de la base de datos hay una mejor opción que utilizar únicamente "where", puedes utilizar "when" que evalua si el filtro existe o no, si está vacío lo ignora, de lo contrario aplica el filtro a la base de datos

Aquí te muestro un ejemplo de cómo podrías utilizar el when para la fecha de inicio y final pero te recomiendo que lo utilices para cada campo que desees filtrar

```
$practices = Practice::query()
    ->when($fecha_inicio, fn($query, $date) => $query->where('inicio', '>=', $date))
    ->when($fecha_termino, fn($query, $date) => $query->where('termino', '<=', $date));
```

When primero evalua si la variable del primer argumento está vacía, si no es así entonces ejecuta la función del segundo argumento, dentro de la función del segundo argumento es donde aplicas el where que deseas

Al utilizar when te aseguras que los filtros únicamente se ejecuten cuando las variables contienen algún valor

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!! excelente solución me acaba de dar, funciona perfecto :)