# Busqueda por un campo con varios filtros en modelos relacionados en laravel livewire

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-livewire

Tengo el siguiente codigo que me filtra los pagos de acuerdo al usuario logueado que creo el pago o al usuario logueado que autorizo el pago. Lo cual funciona bien:

```
public function render() { $pagos = Pago::where('user_id', $this->user_logueado)->orWhere('user_autoriza', $this->user_logueado)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(5); return view('livewire.pago', [ 'pagos' => $pagos ]); }
```

Pero a esos filtros quiero agregarle un filtro de busqueda. Intente lo siguiente pero no funciona:

```
$pagos = Pago::where('user_id', $this->user_logueado)->orWhere('user_autoriza', $this->user_logueado)->orWhere('concepto', 'LIKE', '%'.$this->busqueda.'%')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(5);
```

Comment: Buen día, yo creo que `when` resolvería tu problema, revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/507844/171630).