# ¿Cómo evitar el error si no hay datos en la consulta?

Tags: laravel

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
$offer = Offer::where('from','<=',Carbon\Carbon::now())
                    ->where('to','>=',Carbon\Carbon::now())
                    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                    ->get()->random(1);
```

Funciona pero sino hay alguna fecha coincidente, me muestra el siguiente error:

```
You requested 1 items, but there are only 0 items available.
```

Se me ocurrió hacer esta consulta y luego con un condicional buscar con el `random()`

```
$offer = Offer::where('from','<=',Carbon\Carbon::now())
                    ->where('to','>=',Carbon\Carbon::now())
                    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                    ->get();
```

Obtengo lo siguiente con `dd($offer)`:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1524 ▼ // app\Http\Controllers\HomeController.php:54
  #items: []
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

Se me ocurrió hacer un condicional para esa respuesta con `$offer->isEmpty()`

```
if($offer->isEmpty())
{
    session(['offer' => '']);
}
else
{
 $offer->random(1);
 session(['offer' => $offer]);   
}
```

Pero solo muestra el último registro cuando existe más de una coincidencia de fechas, no funciona el `random()`

Comment: Buen día Joe, por favor revisa [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/507844/171630) respuesta. La función `when` es la que te ayuda a aplicar filtros en caso de que existan y los ignora si están vacíos. Si te sirve no olvides votar.

Comment: Hola. Puedes usar directamente [`inRandomOrder()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#random-ordering) sobre la consulta y combinarlo con `limit()` para indicar **hasta cuantas filas quieres**. Eso no queda claro en la pregunta, estás indicando con esta llamada que quieres un solo registro `random(1)` y luego te quejas de que quisieras ver más registros. ¿Necesitas un solo registro o necesitas `N` cantidad de registros ordenados de forma aleatoria?

Comment: @HeytalePazguato gracias, funcionó perfectamente!

Comment: @A.Cedano muchas gracias por responder. Solo necesito un registro, pero el problema estaba en que a veces no hay registros y me muestraba el error

Comment: Si no hay ofertas que coincidan con esta condición, `get` devuelve una colección vacía. Por lo tanto, puedes usar el método `isEmpty` de la colección para comprobar si la consulta devolvió algún resultado.